# download count and show file size in php

Tags: php, security, filesize

I have a script in which I upload pdf files which user can download.

Now I want to show download counts and file size in MB.

I also want some help to avoid any possible attack because my script is very much simple.

My `download.php` is as below

```
<?php
    include("admin/config.php");
    $id   = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM novels  where id=$id";
    $rs   = mysql_query($sql);
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $pdf  = $row['pdf'];
    $name = $row['title'];
    $path = 'admin/';
    $file = $path.$pdf;
    $filename = $pdf;
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$name-bookspk.net.pdf'");
    header("Content-Length: filesize($file)");
    readfile($file);
    ?>
```

Comment: The usual security hints apply, you will find them when using google. For example your script is vulnerable to sql injection. Stop using the long deprecated mysql extension, start using PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements.

Comment: also make sure that your admin folder is access protected to avoid that your users simply download your files directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For download counts you could save to database

```
$sql = "UPDATE `novels` SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE `id`=".(int)$id;
```

Assuming you have a count column

For download size you should move `filesize` out:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
```

This is for allowing browser to see progress, if you want to display it, it's same, you can store it in database

```
$sql = "UPDATE `novels` SET `size`=".filesize($file)." WHERE `id`=".(int)$id;
```

This should be set when you upload.

Remeber to escape your mysql queries because of vulnerability. For integers is simple as you can cast `(int)`.

Comment: Thanks Mihai Lorga i am new in field of development please tell me in more detail should i have one more column count in novels tables and set to it on uloading page or on download page. And how can i store file size I am using just path in database please don't mind

Comment: When you upload you should store the size.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding caching headers this should reduce the number of times the file is downloaded from the server if you are worried about false positives.

```
<?php
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the future
?>
```

You should probably store the file size in the table when it is uploaded that way you can get all the information out with one call to the database.